# Barcode exchange between neighbouring cells

Tags: cell-biology, virus, synthetic-biology, systems-biology

I am currently interested in equipping animal cells in a tissue with individual barcodes. These barcodes should get amplified in the cells (not to a cell degrading extent, of course), and also transmitted to neighbouring cells.

The question is now, how do I a) insert these barcodes into the cells and b) how do I transmit them to the neighbouring cells.

In the Zador et al. paper "Sequencing the connectome" (http://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.1001411), it was proposed to use a transsynaptic virus like as rabies or pseudorabies, for making that exchange possible between neurons that are synaptically linked. Here, however, I am interested in the directly neighbouring cells and I am insecure whether it makes sense to use transsynaptic virus here.

If so, it would be great, but if not, do you know some alternatives?